# How can we allow iam user to only upload object and deny him to delete and list objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wanna create a S3 bucket that anyone can get object but only iam user can upload an object.

My bucket policy is like this.
Anyone can read objects, but cannot do delete, list, create action.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I attached the below policy for a permission to upload object to a user and the group.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1347416638923",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*" //fixed as @Marcin mentioned

    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that this user can list objects, delete object from javascript.
How can we allow this user to only upload object?

We use Wasabi storage by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket` is a bucket, not objects. Thus it should be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1347416638923",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ExplityDeny",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ExplityDeny2",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick comment! My point is that I want to prevent the user from listing and deleting objects.

Comment: @TsuchidaWataru `PutObject` Is only for upload of objects. No one with these permissions will be able to delete nor list a bucket.

Comment: Yes, I understand this as you said. But the user can actually.
 AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-1",
  accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});

 const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  correctClockSkew: true,
  endpoint: "https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com", 
});
s3.listObjects({ Bucket: bucketName })
      .promise()
      
It returns objects list :(

Comment: @TsuchidaWataru This means that the user has other IAM policies that allow for that.

Comment: I have checked on console many times that the policy is attached to the user

Comment: @TsuchidaWataru Your orginal policy is incorrect to begin with `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"`. My answer shows you have to fix it. For other issues, such as, the user has some other permissions, please make new question.

Comment: Your suggestion is that inside of policy is not a problem. I will create a new question

Comment: @TsuchidaWataru Your policy in the question is incorrect and is a problem. To make it work it must be `arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*`, not `arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket`. Thus my answer solves your incorrect policy that you defined.

Comment: I already fixed what you talk but did not solve my problem

Comment: @TsuchidaWataru Add explict deny as in the updated answer.

Comment: Let me check.....

Comment: Ok, now, I fixed with Deny effect as your answer is wrong,  I could block list objects from this user. But why we need Deny?? Iam user is authorized in default??

Comment: @TsuchidaWataru I already fixed that. Anyway, glad it worked. If so, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks! But before ending, so IAM user is authorized to do anything in default? I thought that Iam user follow as policy says...

Comment: @TsuchidaWataru By default everything is denied. So your user has some other policies allow for the actions. To accept have to press a 'tick' button under upvote/downvote buttons.

Comment: OK, maybe I need some investigations around the console... anyway Thank you!